WPF Menu Item Not Aligning Left Despite Setting HorizontalContentAlignment Or HorizontalAlignment
I'm encountering an issue with a WPF menu where one of the menu items, specifically the "Language" menu item, is not aligning to left along with the other parent menu items despite setting 'HorizontalAlignment="Left"'. Here's a simplified version of my XAML code:
<Menu FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <MenuItem Header="File"/>
    <MenuItem Header="File"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Language" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <MentItem Header="Japanese"/>
        <MenuItem Header="English"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>

Please refer to the image attached of menu item
enter image description here
Despite Setting 'HorizontalAlignment = "Left"' for the "Language" menu item , it still remains centered. I've tried different approaches including setting the 'HorizontalAlignment' directly and using styles, but none seem to work.
any suggestions on how to ensure that the "language" menu item aligns to left along with the other parent menu items ?

why is your flowdirection RightToLEft if you want it to be left aligned?

setting HorizontalAlignment="Right" also does not make any effect

i was talking about the flow direction not the alignment.
